# Vector direction for gravity in a circular orbit

Tags: c#, vector, physics, trigonometry

I am currently working on a project in C# where i play around with planetary gravitation, which i know is a hardcore topic to graps to it's fullest but i like challenges. I've been reading up on Newtons laws and Keplers Laws, but one thing i cannot figure out is how to get the correct gravitational direction.

In my example i only have 2 bodies. A Satellite and a Planet. This is to make is simplify it, so i can grasp it - but my plan is to have multiple objects that dynamically effect each other, and hopefully end up with a somewhat realistic multi-body system.

When you have an orbit, then the satellite has a gravitational force, and that is ofcourse in the direction of the planet, but that direction isn't a constant. To explain my problem better i'll try using an example:

let's say we have a satellite moving at a speed of 50 m/s and accelerates towards the planet at a speed of 10 m/s/s, in a radius of 100 m. (all theoretical numbers) If we then say that the framerate is at 1, then after one second the object will be 50 units forward and 10 units down.

As the satellite moves multiple units in a frame and about 50% of the radius, the gravitational direcion have shifted alot, during this frame, but the applied force have only been "downwards". this creates a big margin of error, especially if the object is moving a big percentage of the radius.

In our example we'd probably needed our graviational direction to be based upon the average between our current position and the position at the end of this frame.

How would one go about calculating this?

I have a basis understanding of trigonometry, but mainly with focus on triangles. Assume i am stupid, because compared to any of you, i probably am.

(I made a previous question but ended up deleting it as it created some hostility and was basicly not that well phrased, and was ALL to general - it wasn't really a specific question. i hope this is better. if not, then please inform me, i am here to learn :) )

Just for reference, this is the function i have right now for movement:

```
foreach (ExtTerBody OtherObject in UniverseController.CurrentUniverse.ExterTerBodies.Where(x => x != this))
{
    double massOther = OtherObject.Mass;

    double R = Vector2Math.Distance(Position, OtherObject.Position);

    double V = (massOther) / Math.Pow(R,2) * UniverseController.DeltaTime;

    Vector2 NonNormTwo = (OtherObject.Position - Position).Normalized() * V;

    Vector2 NonNormDir = Velocity + NonNormTwo;
    Velocity = NonNormDir;

    Position += Velocity * Time.DeltaTime;
}
```

If i have phrased myself badly, please ask me to rephrase parts - English isn't my native language, and specific subjects can be hard to phrase, when you don't know the correct technical terms. :)

I have a hunch that this is covered in keplers second law, but if it is, then i'm not sure how to use it, as i don't understand his laws to the fullest.

Thank you for your time - it means alot!

(also if anyone see multi mistakes in my function, then please point them out!)

Comment: This is a problem with all discrete time-step integrators, not specific to simulating gravity. You might want to read up on it a bit here: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/ :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff That's pretty awesome. thank you - i'll read it and report back when i've tried using it to fix my problem! :)

Comment: I can't link to this question often enough: [What is the correct way of integrating in astronomy simulations?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/what-is-the-correct-way-of-integrating-in-astronomy-simulations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution, it might not be the smartest, but it works, and it's pretty came to mind after reading both Eric's answer and also reading the comment made by marcus, you could say that it's a combination of the two:

This is the new code:

```
foreach (ExtTerBody OtherObject in UniverseController.CurrentUniverse.ExterTerBodies.Where(x =>  x != this))
{
double massOther = OtherObject.Mass;

double R = Vector2Math.Distance(Position, OtherObject.Position);

double V = (massOther) / Math.Pow(R,2) * Time.DeltaTime;

float VRmod = (float)Math.Round(V/(R*0.001), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
if(V > R*0.01f)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < VRmod; x++)
    {
        EulerMovement(OtherObject, Time.DeltaTime / VRmod);
    }
}
else
    EulerMovement(OtherObject, Time.DeltaTime);

}

public void EulerMovement(ExtTerBody OtherObject, float deltaTime)
    {

            double massOther = OtherObject.Mass;

            double R = Vector2Math.Distance(Position, OtherObject.Position);

            double V = (massOther) / Math.Pow(R, 2) * deltaTime;

            Vector2 NonNormTwo = (OtherObject.Position - Position).Normalized() * V;

            Vector2 NonNormDir = Velocity + NonNormTwo;
            Velocity = NonNormDir;



            //Debug.WriteLine("Velocity=" + Velocity);
            Position += Velocity * deltaTime;
    }
```

To explain it:

I came to the conclusion that if the problem was that the satellite had too much velocity in one frame, then why not seperate it into multiple frames? So this is what "it" does now.

When the velocity of the satellite is more than 1% of the current radius, it seperates the calculation into multiple bites, making it more precise.. This will ofcourse lower the framerate when working with high velocities, but it's okay with a project like this.

Different solutions are still very welcome. I might tweak the trigger-amounts, but the most important thing is that it works, then i can worry about making it more smooth!

Thank's everybody that took a look, and everyone who helped be find the conclusion myself! :) It's awesome that people can help like this!

Comment: Please don't post updates as new answers; only post answers as answers. Edit your original post to add new information.

Comment: Actually, updates which are answers should be posted as answers, not as edits to the original post.  CDK is doing it right.

Answer (score 14):

> I am currently working on a project in C# where i play around with planetary gravitation

This is a fun way to learn simulation techniques, programming and physics at the same time.

> One thing I cannot figure out is how to get the correct gravitational direction.

I assume that you are not trying to simulate relativistic gravitation. The Earth isn't in orbit around the Sun, the Earth is in orbit around *where the sun was eight minutes ago*. Correcting for the fact that gravitation is not instantaneous can be difficult. (UPDATE: According to commentary this is incorrect. What do I know; I stopped taking physics after second year Newtonian dynamics and have only the vaguest understanding of tensor calculus.)

You'll do best at this early stage to assume that the gravitational force is instantaneous and that planets are points with all their mass at the center. The gravitational force vector is a straight line from one point to another.

> Let's say we have a satellite moving at a speed of 50 m/s ... If we then say that the framerate is one frame per second then after one second the object will be 50 units right and 10 units down.

Let's make that more clear. Force is equal to mass times acceleration. You work out the force between the bodies. You know their masses, so you now know the acceleration of each body.  Each body has a position and a velocity. The acceleration changes the velocity. The velocity changes the position. So if the particle starts off having a velocity of 50 m/s to the left and 0 m/s down, and then you apply a force that accelerates it by 10 m/s/s down, then we can work out the change to the velocity, and then the change to the position. As you note, at the end of that second the position and the velocity will have both changed by a huge amount compared to their existing magnitudes.

> As the satellite moves multiple units in a frame and about 50% of the radius, the gravitational direcion have shifted alot, during this frame, but the applied force have only been "downwards". this creates a big margin of error, especially if the object is moving a big percentage of the radius.

Correct. The problem is that the frame rate is **enormously** too low to correctly model the interaction you're describing. You need to be running the simulation so that you're looking at tenths, hundredths or thousanths of seconds if the objects are changing direction that rapidly. The size of the time step is usually called the "delta t" of the simulation, and yours is way too large.

For planetary bodies, what you're doing now is like trying to model the earth by simulating its position every few months and assuming it moves in a straight line in the meanwhile. You need to actually simulate its position every few minutes, not every few months.

> In our example we'd probably needed our graviational direction to be based upon the average between our current position and the position at the end of this frame.

You could do that but it would be easier to simply decrease the "delta t" for the computation. Then the difference between the directions at the beginning and the end of the frame is much smaller.

Once you've got that sorted out then there are more techniques you can use. For example, you could *detect* when the position changes too much between frames and go back and redo the computations with a smaller time step. If the positions change hardly at all then increase the time step.

Once you've got *that* sorted, there are lots of more advanced techniques you can use in physics simulations, but I would start by getting basic time stepping really solid first. The more advanced techniques are essentially variations on your idea of "do a smarter interpolation of the change over the time step" -- you are on the right track here, but you should walk before you run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The delta time is already a part of my calculation, as you might have seen -  "UniverseController.DeltaTime;", which is the time it took to do the last frame, times by a TimeScale. I know that this is a problem. but i'd like to be able to move my satellite/partice at a higher speed without losing too much precision. 

It got to be said that i'm not really sure if this is the only problem, it might also be the calculations and implementation that is bad, but this seems to be one source of error, which i can correct. Other problems would be nice to get fixed too though

Comment: @CDK: The computations appear to be correct, assuming that the simulation is scaled so that the gravitational constant is one. Acceleration is m1 x m2 / r^2, so delta v of a particle with mass m1 over a time span of delta t is dt * m1 x m2 / r^2 / m1, the m1's cancel, and you've got a correct computation of delta v. Just make delta t much, much smaller and your simulation will get more accurate.

Comment: is that the only way to do it? if i make it go slower, it would take alot longer time, realtime. With the link Magnus gave http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/ and RK4, would that help. i'm trying to implement it, but i'm not sure if that would really fix the problem. Is reading up on Euler the way to progress? 

would a realistic orbit have the same location after a complete orbit as it has now? that's what you see in most simulations but i'm not sure if that should be true, but if it is, then i have some error as my orbit 'turns'. Thank you btw :)

Comment: Just as an addon - big forces are bound to happen - and i'd really like to know how to handle them. :) there must be some way - and i got a 8-10 hour bustrip tomorrow, so reading is no problem ;)

Comment: @CDK You can get a fairly good approximation with RK4, but Euler isn't reliable for any reasonable time-step (it's just not accurate enough).  There's quite elegant solutions to this problem if you can come up with a state vector of first order ODEs and throw that at RK4, but I'm not sure how great your math background is.

Comment: Re *The Earth isn't in orbit around the Sun, the Earth is in orbit around where the sun was eight minutes ago.* This is VERY wrong,  first discovered by Laplace in 1805. Einstein knew this 110 years later; his general relativity does not say this. A complete general relativistic formulation would make this a PDE rather than an ODE problem. A first order parameterized post-Newtonian approximation stays in the realm of ODEs and works quite nicely for the solar system; see equation 8-1 on page 3 of [Orbital Ephemerides of the Sun, Moon, and Planets](http://iau-comm4.jpl.nasa.gov/XSChap8.pdf).

Comment: @CDK You are right that an object in a Newtonian two-body circular orbit should end up exactly where it started after a period of time.  The same is true of elliptical orbits.  The numerical method you are using to simulate motion is known as the Euler method, and it will only give you an approximate answer.  But if you shrink the timestep (delta t) then you can get arbitrarily close to the right answer.

Comment: Just an FYI, rk4 will still be unstable at long times since it doesn't conserve energy for gravitational systems.  You will need a [symplectic integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator).  A first order method still requires half your integrator to be implicit, but it will remain stable forever, unlike the standard euler or rk4.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with a technique that is almost as simple as the Euler-Cromer integration you've been using but is markedly more accurate. This is the leapfrog technique. The idea is very simple: position and velocity are kept at half time steps from one another.

The initial state has position and velocity at time t<sub>0</sub>. To get that half step offset,  you'll need a special case for the very first step, where velocity is advanced half a time step using the acceleration at the start of the interval and then position is advanced by a full step. After this first time special case, the code works just like your Euler-Cromer integrator.

In pseudo code, the algorithm looks like

```
void calculate_accel (orbiting_body_collection, central_body) {
    foreach (orbiting_body : orbiting_body_collection) {
        delta_pos = central_body.pos - orbiting_body.pos;
        orbiting_body.acc =
            (central_body.mu / pow(delta_pos.magnitude(),3)) * delta_pos;
    }
}

void leapfrog_step (orbiting_body_collection, central_body, delta_t) {
    static bool initialized = false;
    calculate_accel (orbiting_body_collection, central_body);
    if (! initialized) {
        initialized = true;
        foreach orbiting_body {
            orbiting_body.vel += orbiting_body.acc*delta_t/2.0;
            orbiting_body.pos += orbiting_body.vel*delta_t;
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach orbiting_body {
            orbiting_body.vel += orbiting_body.acc*delta_t;
            orbiting_body.pos += orbiting_body.vel*delta_t;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've added acceleration as a field of each orbiting body. This was a temporary step to keep the algorithm similar to yours. Note also that I moved the calculation of acceleration to it's own separate function. That is not a temporary step. It is the first essential step to advancing to even more advanced integration techniques.

The next essential step is to undo that temporary addition of the acceleration. The accelerations properly belong to the integrator, not the body. On the other hand, the calculation of accelerations belongs to the problem space, not the integrator. You might want to add relativistic corrections, or solar radiation pressure, or planet to planet gravitational interactions. The integrator should be unaware of what goes into those accelerations are calculated. The function `calculate_accels` is a black box called by the integrator.

Different integrators have very different concepts of when accelerations need to be calculated. Some store a history of recent accelerations, some need an additional workspace to compute an average acceleration of some sort. Some do the same with velocities (keep a history, have some velocity workspace). Some more advanced integration techniques use a number of techniques internally, switching from one to another to provide the best balance between accuracy and CPU usage. If you want to simulate the solar system, you need an extremely accurate integrator. (And you need to move far, far away from floats. Even doubles aren't good enough for a high precision solar system integration. With floats, there's not much point going past RK4, and maybe not even leapfrog.)

Properly separating what belongs to whom (the integrator versus the problem space) makes it possible to refine the problem domain (add relativity, etc.) and makes it possible to easily switch integration techniques so you can evaluate one technique versus another.

Comment: This might be exactly what i need, and i'll write it down. but at the current time it is far too advanced for me to understand. BTW i am already only using doubles when calculating the actual movement, but what is better to use? i'll try reading your stuff through a couple of times, but for now, the answer i supplied works okay, it eliminates any possiblity of big timestepping, and therefore is somewhat accurrate. but i'll work towards your idea and see if it does the job. my plan is to add rockets and generally more features until this project bores me. thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Switching from the Euler-Cromer technique you are currently using to leapfrog is fairly trivial, and the payoff in increased accuracy is quite immense. You could make this switch within your current architecture with just a tiny number of changes. The code you have shown here is using floats rather than doubles. Floats crater rather quickly when it comes to modeling orbital mechanics. Switching from floats to doubles yields a big payoff without much of a performance hit. (continued)

Comment: With regard to even more precision: Many machines don't support it natively. The `long double` in C/C++ might be just 80 bits wide (e.g., Intel boxes). Modeling the solar system for several thousands of years or longer needs at least quadruple precision (128 bit floating point) to avoid complete precision loss with even the very best of integrators. That means software emulation on a computer that doesn't support quad precision natively, and that in turn means an extremely huge performance hit. There's no reason to go there in your application. Double precision should work quite fine for you.

Comment: Really not sure how to implement the above.. Can i purhaps contact you somewhere with questions about this very concept?

Anyway, if not:
The code i have shown above uses doubles.. "double V = (massOther) / Math.Pow(R,2) * Time.DeltaTime;" and so on... 
Why do you use half acceleration the first frame? "orbiting_body.vel += orbiting_body.acc*delta_t/2.0;"
What's the main difference between what i got and what you are presenting? i can't see any big differences.. sorry. 
I'll try adding decimal where needed.. or should i use another data type? thanks so far..